# Not able to Install Pymc3 in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, pymc3

I tired to install pymc3 using 'pip install pymc3', however, after installation when I tried to import pymc3 I still got the error message : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymc3'. Below is the warning messages I got from running pip install pymc3. Please help me to install pymc3 properly in Jupyter Notebook. Thank you!

```
Looking in indexes: https://ci-repo.aexp.com/repository/pypi/simple/
Collecting pymc3
  Using cached https://ci-repo.aexp.com/repository/pypi/packages/pymc3/3.11.5/pymc3-3.11.5-py3-none-any.whl (872 kB)
Collecting cachetools>=4.2.1
  Using cached https://ci-repo.aexp.com/repository/pypi/packages/cachetools/5.2.0/cachetools-5.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (9.3 kB)
Collecting semver>=2.13.0
  Using cached https://ci-repo.aexp.com/repository/pypi/packages/semver/2.13.0/semver-2.13.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
Collecting typing-extensions>=3.7.4
  Using cached https://ci-repo.aexp.com/repository/pypi/packages/typing-extensions/4.3.0/typing_extensions-4.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (25 kB)
Collecting theano-pymc==1.1.2
  Using cached https://ci-repo.aexp.com/repository/pypi/packages/theano-pymc/1.1.2/Theano-PyMC-1.1.2.tar.gz (1.8 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
Collecting deprecat
  Using cached https://ci-repo.aexp.com/repository/pypi/packages/deprecat/2.1.1/deprecat-2.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (9.8 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas>=0.24.0 in c:\users\ycui2\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from pymc3) (1.4.2)
Collecting fastprogress>=0.2.0
  Using cached https://ci-repo.aexp.com/repository/pypi/packages/fastprogress/1.0.2/fastprogress-1.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
Collecting numpy<1.22.2,>=1.15.0
  Using cached https://ci-repo.aexp.com/repository/pypi/packages/numpy/1.22.1/numpy-1.22.1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (14.7 MB)
Collecting scipy<1.8.0,>=1.7.3
  Using cached https://ci-repo.aexp.com/repository/pypi/packages/scipy/1.7.3/scipy-1.7.3-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (34.3 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: patsy>=0.5.1 in c:\users\ycui2\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from pymc3) (0.5.2)
Collecting dill
  Using cached https://ci-repo.aexp.com/repository/pypi/packages/dill/0.3.5.1/dill-0.3.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (95 kB)
Collecting arviz>=0.11.0
  Using cached https://ci-repo.aexp.com/repository/pypi/packages/arviz/0.12.1/arviz-0.12.1-py3-none-any.whl (1.6 MB)
Collecting filelock
  Using cached https://ci-repo.aexp.com/repository/pypi/packages/filelock/3.7.1/filelock-3.7.1-py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Collecting netcdf4
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='ci-repo.aexp.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /repository/pypi/packages/netcdf4/1.6.0/netCDF4-1.6.0-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='ci-repo.aexp.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /repository/pypi/packages/netcdf4/1.6.0/netCDF4-1.6.0-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='ci-repo.aexp.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /repository/pypi/packages/netcdf4/1.6.0/netCDF4-1.6.0-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='ci-repo.aexp.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /repository/pypi/packages/netcdf4/1.6.0/netCDF4-1.6.0-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='ci-repo.aexp.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /repository/pypi/packages/netcdf4/1.6.0/netCDF4-1.6.0-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='ci-repo.aexp.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /repository/pypi/packages/netcdf4/1.6.0/netCDF4-1.6.0-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (Caused by ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='ci-repo.aexp.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)"))

WARNING: You are using pip version 22.0.4; however, version 22.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Users\ycui2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Comment: That looks like either an internet connection issue on your end, or a server issue, in which case you should retry with the same approach a bit later.

Answer (score 0):

It's recommended to install  **Anaconda** or **Miniforge** first. Furthermore, **PYMC** recently released v 4.0 which is much faster than the previous versions.
After installing any of the two above, you could then create a new environment as:

```
conda create -c conda-forge -n pymc_env "pymc>=4"
conda activate pymc_env
```

More details could be found here https://www.pymc.io/welcome.html